# Find a specified generic DbSet in a DbContext dynamically when I have an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, code-first, dbset

I have following classes and `DbContext`:

```
public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    public Number {get; set;}
}
public class Product : BaseEntity;
{
    public Name {get; set;} 
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    ....
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { set; get; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { set; get; }
    ....
}
```

I have a list of objects that want to add to my context, too, but I don't know how can I find appropriate generic `DbSet` according each entity type dynamically.

```
IList<BaseEntity> list = new List<BaseEntity>();
Order o1 = new Order();
o1.Numner = "Ord1";
list.Add(o1);

Product p1 = new Product();
p1.Name = "Pencil";
list.Add(p1);

Context cntx = new Context();  
foreach (BaseEntity entity in list)
{
      cntx.Set<?>().Add(entity);         
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`DbContext` has a method called `Set`, that you can use to get a non-generic `DbSet`, such as:

```
var someDbSet = this.Set(typeof(SomeEntity));
```

So in your case:

```
foreach (BaseEntity entity in list)
{
      cntx.Set(entity.GetType()).Add(entity);         
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to get generic DbSets also?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would plan to use that, given that you only know the base type at compile time, but FYI, there is also a Set<T>() method which returns the DbSet<T>.

Comment: @PabloRomeo You can use it in a way that I'm about to.  In a abstract class that expects derived classes to define their type.

Comment: @Masoud - To generic dbsets you can create a switch getter and pass the context as a string to get the dbset.

Answer (score 45):

The question does not specify EF version and the proposed answer does not work anymore for Entity Framework Core (in EF Core, `DbContext` does not have a non-generic `Set` method, at least at the date of this answer).

Yet you can still have a working extension method using Jon Skeet's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667981/c-sharp-use-system-type-as-generic-parameter). My code is added below for convenience.

**Update:** Added the generic function call as well returning `IQueryable<T>` thanks to the comment from Shaddix.

```
public static IQueryable Set(this DbContext context, Type T)
{
    // Get the generic type definition
    MethodInfo method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

    return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable;
}

public static IQueryable<T> Set<T>(this DbContext context)
{
    // Get the generic type definition 
    MethodInfo method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in 
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)); 

    return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable<T>;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to have IQueryable<T>: public static IQueryable<T> Set<T>(this DbContext context)
        {

            // Get the generic type definition
            MethodInfo method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

            return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable<T>;
        }

Comment: But this returns an IQueryable and not the DbSet which is needed to add to the context.

Comment: Second method is out of scope as original Set method is already generic typed. Also,original Set method returns a DbSet<T> object. I did not understand how these extensions could be made of use.

Comment: For me this was useful, as all of my Entitys are implementing same interface, and I can then cast IQueryable to IQueryable<Interface>.

Comment: I am using EF Core 5 and the "Set" method is present

Comment: @fededim - "Set" is present, but you cannot call Set(entityToAdd.GetType()) for example, it requires a type.

Comment: @Mike Ok I missed "DbContext does not have a non-generic Set method", now I understand the answer (even though the second method "public static IQueryable<T> Set<T>(this DbContext context)" is already present in DbContext). However I managed to use generics very easily, e.g. ctx.Set<T>().Add(entityToAdd) without needing to use reflection for a non generic Set.

Comment: If you are using EF Core 5.0 and up, since they've [added a new overload](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23683): `DbContext.Set<TEntity>(string)`, you will have to modify this line: `var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);` to `var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).First(m => m.Name == nameof(DbContext.Set) && !m.GetParameters().Any());`

Comment: And if you are using the generic version of `Set<T>()`, you might event don't need this reflection workaround, plz see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71119399)

Answer (score 10):

To avoid error "System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'"
I used version below:

```
    public static IQueryable Set(this DbContext context, Type T)
    {
        var method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethods().Single(p =>
            p.Name == nameof(DbContext.Set) && p.ContainsGenericParameters && !p.GetParameters().Any());
                               
        // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

        return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable;
    }
```

Comment: Strangely, the error was not happening systematically. This seems to have solved it. Thanks.

Comment: It works if you want to read from DbSet but you can not use it for Add or Remove.

Comment: This ambiguous only happens on EF Core 5.0 and up since they've [add a overload for this method](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23683)

Comment: Thanks Sam, I don't see the error any more!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the below proposed version does not work since .NET Core 3.0. You still can get an `IQueryable` back, but you cannot cast it to `DbSet` anymore.

```
IQueryable<TEntity> as DbSet<TEntity> => null
```

What's worse is that starting with EF Core 3.0, the new `FromSqlRaw` and `FromSqlInterpolated` methods (which replace `FromSql`) can only be specified on query roots, i.e. directly on the `DbSet<>` and not on `IQueryable`. Attempting to specify them anywhere else will result in a compilation error.

See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/15704#issuecomment-493230352

Comment: Is it possible to get DbSets back now in 3.1 or 5.0?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get the DbSet in 5.0 Core. I tested it with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite version 5.0.3

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core we only have `Set<TEntity>()` method(s) which have [a constraint that `TEntity` must be a type of class](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/22a533c6e9f8a8463fbc6212804ce599d80a0ff9/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L321-L323), so this prevents you accidentally passing a interface type that EF is impossible to find out any existing DbSet.

So if it's possible, you can always restrict your generic type parameter as the same as `Set<TEntity>()` requiring, for example this will not work:

```cs
public void GetDbSet<T>(DbContext db) {
    db.Set<T>()
//     ~~~~~~~~
// Error CS0452 The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbContext.Set<TEntity>()'
}
```

but this will:

```cs
public void GetDbSet<T>(DbContext db) where T : class {
    db.Set<T>()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @GertArnold the op want to know `how can I find appropriate generic DbSet according each entity type dynamically`, if he's using EFCore then he can just invokes the `dbContext.Set<SomeEntityType>` to get the `DbSet<SomeEntityType>`, I'm just adding a hint to a generic constraint that only allows you to pass a type of class as its generic type param

Comment: Yeah, see the question, not just the title. They don't have a generic class argument.

Comment: Also other answers doesn't update with the fact that the generic variant of method dbContext.Set() is introduced in EF Core 5.0, they've still using slowly runtime reflection to   achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464834

Comment: Yep, because that's left when you only have a type instance. Slow or not.

Answer (score -5):

In addition to Pablo's answer, you can add a class to your project:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity
{
    public static class EntityFrameworkExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object> AsEnumerable(this DbSet set)
        {
            foreach (var entity in set)
            {
                yield return entity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class adds an extention method `AsEnumerable` to `DbSet` instance.

When you want to use it, for example to `Count` or filter a row:

```
var someDbSet = this.Set(typeof(SomeEntity));
var count = (from a in someDbSet.AsEnumerable() select a).Count();
```

Comment: Downvoted because I can't see what this does. DbSet is already IQueryable which extends IEnumerable, and converting it to IEnumerable by iterating all elements is not only nonsense, but also not performant.