# EF Core: how to access DBSets programmatically for Seed purposes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, seeding

In EF Core 3.1+, I would like to seed all DBSets from ANY DbContext with data programmatically with a `Seed()` extension method. The `Seed()` method works beautifully in a non-dynamic situation.

For the manual solution, I can add code (that works adding records for each entity) like:

```
   Categories.AddRange(Categories.ToList().Seed(10));
   Products.AddRange(Products.ToList().Seed(20));
   ...
   SaveChanges();
```

My approach for the dynamic solution that would work for any DbContext is code like this:

```
var entityTypes = myContext.Model.GetEntityTypes();

foreach (var et in entityTypes)
{
    myContext.Set(et.ClrType).ToList().Seed();
}
```

That is referencing a extension method:

```
public static class Queryables
{
    public static IQueryable<object> Set(this DbContext _context, Type t)
    {
        return (IQueryable<object>)_context.GetType()
            .GetMethod("Set")
            .MakeGenericMethod(t)
            .Invoke(_context, null);
    }
}
```

but returns an error:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'

This is for a generic solution using EF 3.1+ where I want to loop through and seed whatever DbSets are in the current context.

I can manually add code (that works adding records for each entity) like:

```
   Categories.AddRange(Categories.ToList().Seed(10));
   Products.AddRange(Products.ToList().Seed(20));
   ...
   SaveChanges();
```

Any idea how to get generic programmatic access to the DBSets so that I can add data to each one?

=== Edit ==========================================================

I updated the extension method as I realized that the duplicate was for multiple methods returned, so I got that part working as below. This code returns the DBSet correctly (sort of):

```
public static IQueryable<object> Set(this DbContext _context, Type T)
{
    return (IQueryable<object>)_context.GetType()
            .GetMethods()
            .First(p => p.Name == "Set" && p.ContainsGenericParameters)
            .MakeGenericMethod(T)
            .Invoke(_context, null);
}
```

Now the code runs without throwing an error, but the item is not added.

Simplifying the code so that the Seed() function is not a factor, I decided to test by just adding a single record as below. I can see the DBSet but still no new record.

```
// Does no throw an error but does not add the item
dynamic newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(et.ClrType);
var set = myContext.Set(et.ClrType);
set.ToList().Add(newItem); // Simplified from .Seed();
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Try replacing `_context.GetType()` with `typeof(DbContext)`

Comment: @ivan-stoev  - Thanks, but with typeof(DbContext) we still get the same error.

Comment: EF Core 5.0? How about `typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set), Type.EmptyTypes)` then.

Answer (score 1):

DbContext has multiple `Set<T>` methods with different parameters.

The easy way to get the right `MethodInfo` is to create a matching delegate;

```cs
var method = new Func<DbSet<object>>(_context.Set<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
method.MakeGenericMethod(T).Invoke( ... );
```

Of course, if you have defined DbSet properties for each type, you could loop through those.

Your other problem, is `set.ToList().Add(...`. Calling `ToList` loads the entire table into a list object, that doesn't know anything about the DbSet it came from. You need to call `DbSet<T>.Add`, not `List<T>.Add`.

I would move your entire seed method into a generic method, make that generic for each type, then call it.

```cs
private void Seed<T>(DbContext context, T obj) =>
    context.Set<T>.Add(obj);

var method = new Action<DbContext, object>(Seed<object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
foreach (var et in entityTypes)
    method.MakeGenericMethod(et.ClrType).Invoke( ... );
```

Comment: Good point about the ToList(). I will take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seemed that this would be a simple thing to do for EF Core but it has not turned out to be so and may not be possible.

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533506/find-a-specified-generic-dbset-in-a-dbcontext-dynamically-when-i-have-an-entity), it seems that recent changes to EF have made this harder to do.

If you jump through hoops with reflection using 'DbContent.Set' to get a list of DbSets, you will find these to actually be of 'InternalDbSet' type with a bunch of warnings about how you should not use them. There is no way to cast them to DbSet or an interface such as IDbSet.

But if anyone has a good solution, please post, as I now intrigued to see whether it can be done.

Comment: By looking at answers on provided link, this problem can be solved. Thanks!