# EF Core 6.0 get InternalDbSet<> from type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, system.reflection, ef-core-6.0, dbset

I do have a problem with EF Core.
I need a Instance of a DBSet<> without knowing the Type
until runtime and method is called.
I need this Instance to add Include Statements dynamically and finally load the information from DB.

I do get an object, which seems to be correct since the debugger recognizes
the DBSet of the type i need, but I cannot cast it, in order to work with the methods and properties.

In addition, it was not possible for me to find a solution in the forums, which is why I am reporting here

I already tried to call the generic method at runtime using reflection,
but failed, since the result is of has the type object.
Is there a way to cast the object to a DBSet of my dynamic type ?

Here is my current attempt to implement the whole thing:

```
public static DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>(DbContext _context) where T : class 
    =>(DbSet<T>)_context.GetType().GetMethod("Set", types: Type.EmptyTypes).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T)).Invoke(_context, null);


/* Return Query to fetch all Models from Database */
private void GetQuery(Type rootType, List<ImportMappingModel> mapping, DbContext context)
{
    var MethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetDbSet");
    var generic = MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(rootType);
    var dbSet = generic.Invoke(null,new object?[]{context} );
}
```

Thank you very much for your help
Regards Luis

Comment: What do you plan to do next with this DbSet? / The `DbContext` has a set of methods: `Update`, `Attach`, `Remove`, `Entry`, etc, that take the `object` type. Use them without knowing the specific types.

Comment: I need to load a Set of Data with multiple Navigation Properties.
I want to figure out which navigation properties i need while runtime, so i do need the include method and after all the toList method

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464834/706346) help?

Comment: The linked answer did not help, since I need a DBSet to work with, not an IQueryable.