# .NET Framework 4.8 (EF 6) code to .NET 6 (EF Core 6)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to convert a .NET Framework 4.8 (EF 6) app to .NET 6 (EF Core 6).

I have this method that is working in .NET 4.8:

```
private async Task<string> someMethod(PropertyInfo propModel, string ident, string text, string val) 
{
    Type nestedModel = propModel.PropertyType;
    DbSet nestedModelDbset = db.Set(nestedModel);

    PropertyInfo propIdent = nestedModel.GetProperty(ident);
    var nestedItem = await nestedModelDbset.Where(propIdent.Name + "== @0", val).Take(1).ToListAsync();
    var nestedInstance = nestedItem.First();
    PropertyInfo propToShow = nestedModel.GetProperty(text);
    string valToShow = (propToShow.GetValue(nestedInstance)).ToString();
    return valToShow;
}
```

I have been trying for hours to convert it to work in .NET 6, but everything I tried failed...

Any help?

**UPDATE**

Ok as per the comments I'll try to give some more info...

basically this has 2 parts: the first one is getting the correct dbset, the second one is querying it to get the desired value.

For the second part:

```
.Where(propIdent.Name + "== @0", val)
```

Ok, I though this was standard LINQ, but it seems this comes from using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` (Dai comment make me dig into it, so thanks)

(check [https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/][1])

Sorry it's an old project and I didn't even know it was using additional nuget packages.

It seems that nuget also works for .NET, so I have installed it in the new project and now that part of code doesn't show errors... but I can't know for sure if it will work until I can have the first part working (getting the dbset)...

**UPDATE #2**

Ok, I swear I have lost hours with this, and after posting it here I got it solved in a matter of minutes. Oh my...

So finally:

**1.** Install nuget package `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

**2.** Added this method from this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496444

```
    public static IQueryable Set(this DbContext context, Type T)
    {
        var method = typeof(DbContext)
                         .GetMethods()
                         .Single(p => p.Name == nameof(DbContext.Set) && p.ContainsGenericParameters && !p.GetParameters().Any());
                           
        // Build a method with the specific type argument you're interested in
        method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

        return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable;
    }
```

**3.** Then my corrected method is:

```
    private async Task<string> someMethod(PropertyInfo propModel, string ident, string text, string val) 
    {
        Type nestedModel = propModel.PropertyType;
        //DbSet nestedModelDbset = db.Set(nestedModel);
 
        IQueryable nestedModelDbset = db.Set(nestedModel);

        PropertyInfo propIdent = nestedModel.GetProperty(ident);
        var nestedItem = await nestedModelDbset.Where(propIdent.Name + "== @0", val).Take(1).ToListAsync();
        var nestedInstance = nestedItem.First();

        PropertyInfo propToShow = nestedModel.GetProperty(text);
        string valToShow = (propToShow.GetValue(nestedInstance)).ToString();

        return valToShow;
    }
```

and voila, it's working!

I love this site XD

Comment: _but everything I tried failed..."_ - okay, but you need to give us an example... otherwise I'm going to choose to believe that you only tried sipping a differernt flavour of tea today and presumably that's what didn't work.

Comment: `.Where(propIdent.Name + "== @0", val)` <-- This `Where` method you're using is not Linq (either `Enumerable` or `Queryable` because you're passing-in `String` not `Expression<Func<>>` arguments. So clearly _something is going on_ here but you haven't given us any details...

Comment: @Dai: you are right, please check question update

Answer (score 0):

I trust this code will be beneficial to you:

```
private async Task<string> SomeMethodAsync(PropertyInfo propModel, string ident, string text, string val)
{
    Type nestedModelType = propModel.PropertyType;
    var nestedModelDbSet = db.Set(nestedModelType);

    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(nestedModelType, "x");
    var propIdentExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, ident);
    var equalsExpr = Expression.Equal(propIdentExpr, Expression.Constant(val));
    var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(equalsExpr, paramExpr);

    var whereMethod = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Where), new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) });
    var whereGenericMethod = whereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(nestedModelType);

    var whereQuery = (IQueryable<object>)whereGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { nestedModelDbSet, lambdaExpr });
    var nestedItem = await ((IAsyncEnumerable<object>)whereQuery.AsAsyncEnumerable()).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (nestedItem != null)
    {
        var propToShow = nestedModelType.GetProperty(text);
        var valToShow = propToShow.GetValue(nestedItem)?.ToString();
        return valToShow;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: But you didn’t even say why

Comment: @hs.jalilian  Thanks, I got it solved but I will try your suggestion too when I have some spare time.

Comment: A good answer should explain why this code works!