# How to get class reference from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core, I can get a list of all my entities, and find a specific one by name:

```
var entities = _context.Model.GetEntityTypes();
var entity = (from e in entities where e.Name == $"MyNamespace.Models.{entityname}" select e).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(entity.Name);   //example output:  MyNamespace.Models.Car
```

So I can access the entity name (or Model name) as a string, and now need to make that a class type for use by CsvHelper, because it requires that:

```
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<SomeClass>().ToList();  //typical use - not my code.
```

I tried to convert my entity  to a Type as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string), so I do:

```
Assembly assem = typeof(MyNamespace.Models.Car).Assembly;
Type myType = Type.GetType(entity.Name);   //entity.Name example: MyNamespace.Models.Car
var records = csvReader.GetRecords<myType>().ToList();
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

```
 error CS0118: 'myType' is a variable but is used like a type
```

I don't understand why I get that error, or how to proceed.

Comment: You can't do this - you're trying to use `System.Type` as generic type parameter. See similar question on how to [use `System.Type` as generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667999/997668)

Comment: Thanks, however I discovered that CsvHelper also supports calling like this:  GetRecords(Type type). (Thank you Josh Close!).  So I can use the type that was determined from string, and don't need to use a  generic type parameter.