# Passing dynamic argument into Linq ...OfType<type>

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Type type = someObject.GetType();
if (someCollection.OfType<type>().Any())
{
    // some code
}
```

And the problem is that `OfType<type>()` only takes types directly like `<T>` and you can't pass it as an argument... is there something I can do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You can, but you have to do a bit of reflection.

Comment: Why not just `.Any(type.IsInstanceOfType)`?

Comment: Please, refer to this question [C# use System.Type as Generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667981/c-sharp-use-system-type-as-generic-parameter)

Comment: No need for reflection, you can just use `Where(o => type.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())` rather than `OfType`. The close duplicate contains more details on that (scroll down past the first answer).

Comment: Thank you guys! The reason why is very simple. Because I have no idea what I'm doing :) I'm still just learning how to use Linq. But your advice worked and I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do.