# How to filter items from collection based on type stored in variable

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, casting

I have the following hierarchy:

```
class Animal

class Dog : Animal

class Cat : Animal
```

I have a `List<Animal>` collection and want to make a method that will return all cats or all dogs. However I can't figure out how to filter the list elements based on a type variable. So like this:

```
int AnimalsOfType(Type animalType)
{
    // Gives error "animalType is a variable but is used like a type".
    return animals.OfType<animalType>().Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

int AnimalsOfType(Type animalType)
{
    return animals.Count(a => a.GetType() == animalType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why can't a variable ot type `Type` be used as a type?

Comment: You cannot pass a variable of Type `System.Type` as a generic parameter to a generic function directly. 

The reason is: Generic parameter are replaced when the code is compiled 

[Read this answer which explain more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667999/9482050)

Comment: Can be further simplified to
`animals.Count(a => a.GetType() == animalType);`

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method here is to use `MakeGenericMethod` and `CreateDelegate` to create delegates to generic methods. You can cache these delegates in a dictionary

```cs
static Dictionary<Type, Func<List<Animal>, int>> _methods = new Dictionary<Type, Func<List<Animal>, int>>();

static int CountOfType<T>(List<Animal> source) =>
    source.Count(a => a is T);  
    
int AnimalsOfType(List<Animal> animals, Type animalType)
{
    if(!_methods.TryGetValue(animalType, out var dlgt))
    {
        dlgt = (Func<List<Animal>, int>)
             this.GetType().GetMethod("CountOfType")
                  .MakeGenericMethod(animalType)
                  .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<List<Animal>, int>)));
        _methods[animalType] = dlgt;
    }
    return dlgt(animals);
}
```

There is a single small startup cost the first time you call this method, per type.